# Hadoop : Folder Compression

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to archive and compress a directory in HDFS?
I have used pig but it is taking large amount of time. Is there any better way for this ?

Comment: @charan compressing a folder and a file is different

Comment: There's a reason it takes time. It all depends on the input size and compression type. And Pig reads the content to local mappers, then compresses, then re-uploads. There's no quick way to compress within HDFS